# how to call a gradle task which inside a jar with a parameter

Tags: gradle

I want to run a gradle task embedded in a jar, the jar which I am not producing myself. Is this even possible? I could also paste in the gradle task into my local build.gradle and run it but all the code would still need to reference the jar to actually run the main class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the jar which contains the *Task* you want to use in your buildscript classpath, using `buildscript` block. This way, you will be able to import and use this *Task* class in your build script. The `buildscript` block is generally used to add external Gradle Plugin jars into the script classpath, so that they can be applied, but you can also reference jars that provide no *plugin* implementation but only *Task* implementation classes.

**Example**

Assuming that:

- the coordinates of the external jar is `org.company.gradle:custom-tasks:0.1`
- the *Task* implementation class is `org.company.gradle.tasks.MyTask`
- the *Task* implementation has a configurable property `message`

Then you can implement your build script as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // define repositories
    }
    dependencies {
        // make the external jar available in the build script classpath
        classpath "org.company.gradle:custom-tasks:0.1"
    }
}

// use the Task 
task 'myTask'(type: org.company.gradle.tasks.MyTask) {
    message = "custom message"
}
```